# HCF Python Program Not Debugging

Tags: python, visual-studio

```
def computeHCF(x,y):
    if x>y:
        small=int(y)
    else:
        small=int(x)
    for i in range(1,small+1):
        if ((x%i)==0) and ((y%i)==0)):
            hcf=i
    return hcf  

a=input('Enter first number: ')
b=input('Enter second number: ')
print('The HCF of ',a,' and ',b,' is ',computeHCF(a,b))
```

I tried this code on Python to compute HCF and it showed:

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
not all arguments converted during string formatting
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\Python\findhcf.py", line 7, in computeHCF
    if ((x%i)==0 and (y%i)==0):
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\Python\findhcf.py", line 13, in <module>
    print('The HCF of ',a,' and ',b,' is ',computeHCF(a,b))
```

Please help my to figure the mistake that I have done in this program, I tried many things but it didn't work at all. Thank you.

Comment: `input(..)` returns a string. Make sure you convert it to int using `int()`.

Comment: Thank you so much @Austin ! That solved it!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you are using Python 3.x, which is causing this error. In Python 3.x input() reads the value as a 'string' and not 'int'. You can read integer like this.

```
a=int(input('Enter first number: '))
```

Comment: If some answer works, you should always 'accept' it.

Comment: Whoops, my bad, @ShivRajawat I didn't know that! (: